# How to check two lists for match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to know which would be the best way to check two lists of text within Excel. I have one list, that has file names which exist on my HDD and I wish to reference these against a second list, of file names which I should have received to make sure that none of them are missing.

I did try

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet9!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Although this brings back a value it does not match the value in the list.

If you require more clarification then let me know.
I can't post images at the moment so hopefully this (example) will clear things up a bit.

List of files supposedly sent:-

- CC-2245-SXV.PDF
- CC-2222-SXV.PDF
- CC-0001-SXV.PDF
- DF-2322-CDSC.PDF
- CC-6221-SXV.PDF

File names on my HDD:-

- CC-0001-SXV.PDF
- CC-0161-SXV.PDF
- CC-2221-CCXV.PDF
- CC-6221-SXV.PDF
- DF-2322-CDSC.PDF

The reason I want to automate this is because I'm dealing with 1000's of files.

Comment: Plesae give us your initial input, and your expected output based on that input.

Comment: Sorry to confuse no there is two columns in total.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a VBA function:

```
Function FULLMATCH(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean

    Dim cell As Range
    FULLMATCH = False

    For Each cell In Range1.Cells
        If (cell.Value <> Range2.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    FULLMATCH = True
End Function
```

And use it like this example:

```
=FULLMATCH(A:A;B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

shA.t's answer would likely be easier long term but if you want to go with a Vlookup you could do something like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(HDD,Sent,1,FALSE)),CONCATENATE("File not sent: ",HDD),VLOOKUP(HDD,Sent,1,FALSE))
```

In this case I put the list of files on the HDD in a named range simply named HDD and a list of sent files in a named range named Sent. You could just as easily replace the named ranges with something like Sheet1!B1:B5 if you wanted to.

If it fails to find a file in the Sent list that is in the HDD list thus returning #N/A instead it returns a message telling you which file from the HDD list wasn't sent.

If you plan on just having the three columns (HDD list, Sent list, and formula) on a single worksheet you could remove the rest and just use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(HDD,Sent,1,FALSE)
```

But the first formula will work if you have the two lists in separate worksheets or separate excel files and make it easier to see which files are missing.